# calculating data from other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have written this query to show total working time and overtime of an employee on particular date (if he has came). i want if for a particular date person's INtime and OutTime are empty then put 00:00 in his intime, outtime, totalworkingtime, overtime e.g. it's sunday so obviously no InTime and OutTime then it should show 00:00 in time columns. Note: dates are only entered if person InTIme is mentioned otherwise no DateVisited.

e.g.

```
EmplID  EmplName ShiftID intime Outtime totalworking overtime  dateVisited
0000001 John     S001    00:00  00:00   00:00:       00:00     2013-12-01
```

Query:

```
WITH    times
          AS ( SELECT t1.EmplID
                   ,t3.EmplName
                   ,MIN(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
                   ,MAX(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
                   ,t4.ShiftId AS ShiftID
                   ,t4.StAtdTime AS ShStartTime
                   ,t4.EndAtdTime AS ShEndTime
                   ,CAST(MIN(t1.RecTime) AS DATETIME) AS InTimeSub
                   ,CAST(MAX(t2.RecTime) AS DATETIME) AS TimeOutSub
                   ,t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
                FROM AtdRecord t1
                INNER JOIN AtdRecord t2
                    ON t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID
                       AND t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
                       AND t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
                INNER JOIN HrEmployee t3
                    ON t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID
                INNER JOIN AtdShiftSect t4
                    ON t3.ShiftId = t4.ShiftId
                GROUP BY t1.EmplID
                   ,t3.EmplName
                   ,t1.RecDate
                   ,t4.ShiftId
                   ,t4.StAtdTime
                   ,t4.EndAtdTime)
    SELECT EmplID
           ,EmplName
           ,ShiftId AS ShiftID
           ,InTime
           ,[TimeOut]
           ,CONVERT(CHAR(5), CAST([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub AS TIME), 108) TotalWorkingTime
           ,[DateVisited]
           ,CASE WHEN [InTime] IS NOT NULL
                      AND [TimeOut] IS NOT NULL
                 THEN CONVERT(CHAR(5), CASE WHEN CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime
                                                 AND ShiftID = 'S002'
                                            THEN LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(ms,
                                                                                   DATEDIFF(ms,
                                                                                            CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME),
                                                                                            CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)),
                                                                                   0), 108), 5)
                                            WHEN CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime
                                                 AND ShiftID = 'S001'
                                            THEN LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(ms,
                                                                                   DATEDIFF(ms,
                                                                                            CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME),
                                                                                            CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)),
                                                                                   0), 108), 5)
                                            ELSE '00:00'
                                       END, 108)
                 ELSE 'ABSENT'
            END AS OverTime
        FROM times
        ORDER BY EmplID
           ,ShiftID
           ,DateVisited
```

Comment: can you clarify your question? I'm not sure what is it that you are asking.

Comment: e.g. You are an employee and don't come one sunday or any holiday then for that date your Id and mae etc should appear but times should be 00:00 mean no data for that day.

Comment: dates onlt gt entered when person inTime are mentioned only. I am getting it from bio,etric device actually. 

INTIME then datevisited is feeded but problem is that if person is absent then no InTime and no date visited so how to determine

Comment: So you are saying you want every possible date to be entered, not just the dates where an employee came in, but for days like Sundays and holidays, you want the times to be 00:00? Is that right?

Comment: @R_Scott exactly sir, 100% like this

Answer (score 0):

For your case, the best way to do this is create a table that will give you minutes to Fraction calculation.

For Example:  1 min = 0.02 hour , 40 min =0.67 hour

After this you can relate with your query that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This works to give you what it sounds like you're asking for. I'm sure there are probably better solutions, but this popped into my head as a way to do it. Most of this was where I created temp tables to work with. From the asterisks down is the query that does the work.

```
--created a table filled with the dates of every day between now and the 14th.
DECLARE @days datetime
SET @days = GETDATE()
CREATE TABLE #daylist (
dateofwork datetime)
WHILE @days < '02/14/2014'
  BEGIN
    SELECT @days
    INSERT INTO #daylist (dateofwork)
    VALUES (@days)
    SET @days = DATEADD(d, 1, @days)
  END

--created a table of employees with work dates and times
CREATE TABLE #emps (
ID varchar(10),
timein varchar(10),
timedone varchar(10),
dateofwork datetime
)
--inserted values for that table
INSERT INTO #emps (ID, timein, timedone, dateofwork)
VALUES ('123', '08:00', '17:00', '02/12/2014'),
   ('789', '07:00', '18:00', '02/11/2014')

--********************************************************
--used this to get each employee matched with every date showing
--00:00 on all the days they didn't work
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,d.dateofwork,101) AS dateofwork, 
t.ID,
ISNULL(timein, '00:00') AS timein, 
ISNULL(timedone, '00:00') AS timedone
FROM  #daylist d 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT e.ID, d.dateofwork
              FROM #emps e, #daylist d) AS t ON CONVERT(varchar,d.dateofwork,101) =     CONVERT(varchar,t.dateofwork,101)
   LEFT JOIN #emps e ON CONVERT(varchar,e.dateofwork,101) =     CONVERT(varchar,t.dateofwork,101)
          AND e.ID = t.id
ORDER BY dateofwork
```